# Confused about execution of smart contract and being mined

Tags: solidity, contract-development

As I understand, if you call a smart contract function, a miner will pick it up, include it on a block, and execute it. However, assuming you have sufficient gas, what if the computation time to execute the smart contract function takes more time than one block? I feel like I may be misunderstanding something about what it means to be “included on the block.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in a smart contract can possibly take that long. There's a gas limit per block.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Then, is there no way to “wait” and execute part of the smart contract on another block? I know there is an “Ethereum alarm clock” dapp bur I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to do this but if the gas limit stops me, then I guess not.

Comment: No, there's no way inside a smart contract to do that. (As you said, you can set up a system through interaction with external actors to do something like that.)